# Swarm web3 upload file from browser

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, nodejs, swarm

Im following this [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-bzz.html) to implement an application that I pick a file with an input tag

```
<input id="upload" type="file" />
```

and im tyring to upload using web3 js :

```
 document.querySelector('input#upload').click();
    let inputElement = document.getElementById("upload");
    inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
    function handleFiles() {
       let fileList = this.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
       definedFile = fileList[0];
       web3.bzz.upload({data: definedFile}) // could also be "directory" or "data"
                .then(console.log);
    }
```

The problem is , my return value is being false.

I've already tested my web3.bzz uploading a local file like :

```
web3.bzz.upload({
        path: "/path/to/my/file",      // path to data / file / directory
        kind: "directory",           // could also be "file" or "data"
        defaultFile: "/test.png"}) // optional, and only for kind === "directory"
        .then(function(hash){
            console.log("Uploaded :" , hash);
        })
        .catch(console.log);
```

and it worked beautifully.

It swarm able to upload buffered files?

Comment: Did you tried to use `web3.bzz.upload({file: definedFile}) ` ?

Comment: @EduardoPereira  yeap and didnt worked :(

Comment: are you sure this javascript is complete/correct? `definedFile` is set inside the function `handleFiles`, but your upload is called right after the function definition?

Comment: @faboolous , you are right the code it's incorrect. Still, even when I call it on the function , didn't worked

Comment: Now I've got a new issue : ```node:4640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): ReferenceError: document is not defined
(node:4640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
``` , so it's seems the function picker it's being called, but it's not being able to create the document.

Comment: To me it still looks like you are not sharing the complete code, which then makes it difficult to help you. You should share more info. Are you using node.js? Is this server-side or in a browser?

Comment: I’m on a server-sode node.js running a express application

Comment: well I'd say you can't use `document`, `querySelector` or `getElementById` server-side - these are javascript browser concepts, used to get elements from a DOM structure in HTML. Or I just don't understand your setup.